# How do I SELECT a unix timestamp, given a datetime column?

Tags: sql-server

Given a table with a datetime column, how do I select back the date values as [unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a unix timestamp represents a given point in time simply by specifying the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 at midnight, the answer is simple.

```
datediff(second,'1970-01-01',[myDateColumn])
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle that demonstrates [use of datediff to create unix timestamps from datetime columns](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2675/5).

Note that a Unix timestamp is the number of seconds elapsed since 1970-01-01 00:00 *UTC*. If your datetime value doesn't represent a UTC time, you'll be off by the number of seconds that that datetime's timezone is off from UTC. If your timezone observes daylight savings, this will vary throughout the year.

Comment: I have posted this self-answer because it took me waaaaay to long to figure this out, even with SE and google's help...

Comment: I am concerned that this naive solution will run into trouble regarding timezones.  I haven't investigated further since timezones are not a concern in my local use case.

Comment: Your intuition is correct re: timezones. Specifically, Unix timestamp is the number of seconds elapsed since 1970-01-01 00:00 *UTC*. If your datetime value doesn't represent a UTC time, you'll be off by the number of seconds that that datetime's timezone is off from UTC. Note that if your TZ observes daylight saving, this will vary throughout the year.

Comment: Thanks, @Ben.  I've added that to the answer.  In other news, at this point the question and answer certainly contain all the information I was looking for at the time, so I'll mark it as accepted.